# Component based composition

Tags: java, swing

Can anyone assist me to implement a component-based project? I have designed two components i.e calculator and engine (source codes below) which need to be inside any of the swing components (either `JList` , `JTree`, or any). Then there should be an ability of dragging any of the two components (calculator or engine) unto the editor pane for composition using a connector (code give below). If the composition is right, let the composite return unto the palette where the initial components were dragged from.

Components:

```
public class Engine {

    private String name = "";
    private boolean running = false;
    private int speed;

    public Engine(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void start() {
        if (!running) {
            running = true;
            System.out.println("Engine starts.");
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Engine already starts.");
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (running) {
            running = false;
            speed = 0;
            System.out.println("Engine stops.");
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Engine already stops.");
    }

    public void setSpeed(int speed) {
        if (speed >=0)
            this.speed = speed;
    }
}
```

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

```
public class Calc {

    public Calc() {

        }

    public Double squareRoot(Double a_double){
        return Math.sqrt(a_double);
    }

    // pre an_int >= 0
    public synchronized Integer factorial(Integer an_int){
        int fact=1;
        for(int i=1;i<=an_int;i++){
            fact *= i;
        }
        return fact;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param an_int
     * @return the squared root of the input integer 
     */
    public Integer getSquareRoot(Integer an_int){
        return (int) Math.sqrt(an_int);
    }


    public Double getSquareRoot(Double aDouble){
        return Math.sqrt(aDouble);
    }

    /**
     * Converts an Integer object into a Double object. 
     * 
     * @param an_int The Integer to be converted.
     * @return The Double object representing the same value.
     *  
     */
    public Double integerToDouble(Integer an_int){
        return new Double(an_int.intValue());
    }

    /**
     * Converts a Double object into an Integer object. Decimal digits are
     * truncated. Useful when passing the output of a method as the input to another.
     * 
     * @param a_double The Double to be converted.
     * @return The Integer object representing the same value.
     *  
     */
    public Integer doubleToInteger(Double a_double){
        return new Integer(a_double.intValue());
    }


    public Integer sum(Integer a, Integer b) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return a+b;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a string representation of the calculator.
     */
    public String toString(){
        return("Calculator computation unit:\n"+super.toString());
    }


    void doNothing(){

    }}
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: Why are you using the boxed numbers rather than primitives?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to leverage an existing GUI editor, where the one in Netbeans is rumoured to be good.

You will then need to add your components to the component palette.  Check the Netbeans online help for further information.

Answer (score 0):

Start with NetBeans, [take a look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612984/how-to-make-industry-standard-desktop-java-applications/1748377#1748377), i give full details of how to create a component in NetBeans.